# Establish connection from apache angular app to rest api node js

Tags: node.js, angular, apache, express

I deployed an angular app hosted in apache server into an VPS. And I got an URL 
    something 
    like this :
    http://myip.com/angularApp/ 
    In same VPS is running pm2 with a REST api developed in nodejs using express (CORS are 
    enabled).
    Route for these are like:
    http://myip.com:4000/api/users,  
    http://myip.com:4001/api/clients
    
    Problem is, when angularApp tries to consume the REST api, the URLs are =>
    http://myip.com/api/users,  
    http://myip.com/api/clients
    
    fyi:
    
    I also tried to do the same in nginx but it not worked too.
    
    Works fine in: Running static angular files in express. Running angular in dev mode 
    only consuming rest api.
    
    Any idea for solving this? ty

Comment: You need to use the port number to differentiate the request b/w client and server which are running on same domain name.

Comment: can you give me an example?